# From string to different time zone not working in ruby

Tags: ruby, time, timezone

I have field in my table as "start_time" as string. E.g Value is "`2014-02-07T02:00:00Z`". This is provided by API.
We want to show this time as per the client time zone (May EST, Central, IST, Pacific time). For testing In my system I set time zone as (Estern Time (US&Canada))
I tried

```
start_at = "2014-02-07T02:00:00Z"
start_time = Time.parse(start_at.chop!)
gm_start_time = Time.gm(start_time.strftime('%Y'), start_time.strftime('%b'), start_time.strftime('%d').to_i, start_time.strftime('%H'), start_time.strftime('%M'), start_time.strftime('%S'))
event_start_time = gm_start_time.localtime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')

Result as:
2014-02-07 02:00:00 -0500 ==> start_time
2014-02-06 21:00:00 -0500 ==> gm_start_time
"02/06/2014 21:00"        ==> event_start_time
```

Here I am trying is

1. convert the string to Time object
2. Converting that time to GMT
3. From GMT trying to find equivalent "loca ltime"

If central time is 2014-02-07T02:00:00Z, then local time should 2014-02-07T03:00:00Z

Why I am getting Feb 6th 21 hours. This is -5 hours from expected result. My timezone also -5 hours.

(Time is 24 hours format)

Anyone have any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `gm = Time.parse(start_at.chop!).utc`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some issues with understanding how to handle the time zones. The `Z` letter at the end of the timestamp indicates that the time is UTC, so apparently your API provides you the time in UTC. When you remove it by using `chop!` (note that you could simply use `chop` anyway), Ruby cannot tell anymore what the time zone is, so it's going to use your local time zone by default (I live in UTC+08:00):

```
1.9.3-p484 :006 >  Time.parse("2014-02-07T02:00:00Z")
=> 2014-02-07 02:00:00 UTC 
1.9.3-p484 :007 > Time.parse("2014-02-07T02:00:00")
=> 2014-02-07 02:00:00 +0800
```

Using `Time.gm` then becomes unnecessary since you already have the time in UTC (assuming the API always sends you timestamps in UTC).

Also, what you are exactly trying to achieve is a bit confusing because you have at least one typo in your post (unless you're trying to obtain a local time in Europe).